# Height calculation of algebraic numbers

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

An *absolute value* on a field $F$ is a function $|\cdot |:F\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying

1. $|x|=0 \iff x=0;$
2. $|xy|=|x||y|$ for all $x\in F$;
3. $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ for all $x,y\in F$.

If also $|x+y|\leq\max\{|x|, |y|\},$ then  $|\cdot |$ is called non-archimedean (otherwise it is called archimedean).
Two absolute values $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ on $F$ are called equivalent if there exists $c > 0$ such that $|x|_1=|x|_2^c$ for all $x\in F$. An equivalence class of absolute values on $F$ is called a *place* on $F$ and the set of all places on $F$ is denoted by $M_F$.

The *height* of $\textbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)\in F^n$ with respect to $F$ is defined as
$$H(\textbf{x})=\prod\limits_{\nu\in M_F}\max(|x_1|_\nu,...,|x_n|_\nu).$$

Take $F={\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/N}, 2^{2/N},...,2^{(N-1)/N}]}$. I want to calculate $H(1,2^{1/N}, 2^{2/N},...,2^{(N-1)/N})$ with respect to $F$. Here is what I got:

\begin{align*}
    \begin{split}
&H(1,2^{1/N}, 2^{2/N},...,2^{(N-1)/N})=\\
&\prod\limits_{\nu\in M_F}\max(1, |2^{1/N}|_\nu,...,|2^{(N-1)/N}|_\nu)=\prod\limits_{\nu\in M_F}\max(1, |2|^{1/N}_\nu,...,|2|^{(N-1)/N}_\nu)=\\
&\prod\limits_{\nu\in M_F}\max(1, |2|^{(N-1)/N}_\nu)= \prod\limits_{\substack{\nu\in M_F \\ \nu\; \textrm{archimedean}}}\max(1, |2|^{(N-1)/N}_\nu),
    \end{split}
\end{align*}
where the last equality holds as $|2|_\nu\leq 1$ for $|\cdot|_\nu$ non-archimedean. Also, I think that $|2|_\nu=2$ for archimedean $\nu$ and if this is correct then it remains to find the number of archimedean absolute values on $F$. I think this number is equal to $2^{N-1}$, which then leads to the final answer $H(1,2^{1/N}, 2^{2/N},...,2^{(N-1)/N})=\bigg(2^{(N-1)/N}\bigg)^{2^{N-1}}$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $N$ embeddings $\Bbb{Q}[2^{1/N}]\to \Bbb{C}$ and you need to count twice the complex places, so you get $$H(1,2^{1/N}, 2^{2/N},...,2^{(N-1)/N})=2^{N-1}$$
The complex places are counted twice because we want $$\forall a\in F^*, \qquad H(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=H(ax_1,\ldots,ax_n)$$

Comment: The absolute values on $\Bbb{Q}[2^{1/N}]$ are obtained by sending $\sum_{j=0}^J c_j 2^{j/N}$ to the complex number $\sum_{j=0}^J c_j e^{2i\pi mj/N} 2^{j/N}$

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask for a proof/reference for this?

Comment: Also, by definition, the absolute value should take a real nonnegative value. Sorry if my questions and comments don't make much sense, I am just trying to understand this concept

Comment: For a  number field $F$, for any field homomorphism $\sigma:F\to\Bbb{C}$ you have an Archimedian absolute value $|a|_\sigma = |\sigma(a)|_\Bbb{C}$.  They are all of this form. Write $F=\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ then you get one absolute value for each root of $\beta$'s minimal polynomial, though a pair of complex conjugate roots give the same absolute value.